# HTML 5 Canvas addHitRegion not working on iOS (undefined is not a function)

Tags: javascript, ios, html, canvas

I'm building out a clickable canvas overlaying an image for my website. On the desktop, everything is working fine. I'm looping through a set of coordinates and drawing various clickable shapes. On iOS, however, my loop draws the first shape and then apparently hits an error on the last line of this snippet, where I try to give the region an id. It stops drawing when it hits this point.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('coveringCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  if (mapData.paths.length > 0) {
    for (var x = 0; x < mapData.paths.length; x++) {
      context.beginPath();
      var points = mapData.paths[x];
      for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        var point = points[i];
        if (i == 0) {
          context.moveTo(point.x * multiplier, point.y * multiplier);
        } else {
          context.lineTo(point.x * multiplier, point.y * multiplier)
        }
      }
      context.closePath();
      context.lineWidth = 1;
      context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
      context.stroke();
      context.addHitRegion({ id: x });
    }
  }
```

Everything works properly on the desktop. Is this functionality not supported by iOS, and if not, is there a workaround? I couldn't find any documentation. The error being thrown is

> undefined is not a function

which seems to indicate that addHitRegion is not available in iOS. Is there any way to get click events for these shapes in iOS?

Edited to add the function where I'm adding the click event to the canvas.

```
function drawMap() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('coveringCanvas');
  canvas.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    if (event.region) {
     alert('You clicked parcel ' + event.region);
    }
  }, false);
}
```

Comment: add this before `var context` - `canvas.addEventListener("click", mouseClickEvent, false);`. Also could you provide a Fiddle of the problem so people can test and answer this for you.

Comment: I'll try to get a fiddler set up. Regarding the click event, I do have that in a previous function, and it seems to be firing, but without a way to assign ids to regions, I can't tell where I'm clicking. I'm using complex shapes so it's difficult to detect my position by just checking coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the support for `addHitRegion()` is pretty slim on mobile devices. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/addHitRegion#Browser_compatibility), these devices are the only one supporting it at the moment of this writing (disclaimer: it's not certain MDN is entirely up to date; caniuse.com does not report any on this method):

[image: support mobile]

The situation is a little better on desktop, but not by much (and in both Chrome and Firefox you must enable it through flags):

[image: support desktop]

I am not aware of any known workarounds (polyfill; it would be difficult to write one as it integrates with the event system) at the moment of writing this. You have to use the manual laborious method of doing this using boundary checks and/or `isPointInPath()` (`isPointInStroke()`).

Comment: Thank you. Thanks what I was afraid of. I'm pursuing an alternative method of using SVG. Thanks for your help!